# which user agent request library is using by default

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am developing Node-Js application and I am using Request library and I just want to know which user-agent by default Request library is using?

Comment: Judging from the documentation, it doesn't send it unless you set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [httbin.org](https://httpbin.org) for things like that:

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://httpbin.org/headers', (error, response, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

The output of the above script is the following:

```
"headers": {
  "Connection": "close",
  "Host": "httpbin.org"
}
```

So it seems like by default the request library doesn't send a "User-Agent" header at all...